# knockout template html file in adminhtml area is not rendering

Tags: adminhtml, knockoutjs, knockout

I am trying to initialize the knockout component in the admin html area, the respective code is below.

> phtml file to initialize ko template

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \JC\ChatSupport\Block\Adminhtml\ChatList $block
 */
?>
<div id="chatlist" class="chatlist" data-bind="scope:'chatlist'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    phtml
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#chatlist": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "chats": {
                        "component": "JC_ChatSupport/js/component/chatlist",
                        "template" : "JC_ChatSupport/chatlist"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

> js component file

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent',
        'ko'
    ], function ($, Component, ko) {
        'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            console.log("hello, this is loading");
        },
    });
    }
);
```

> html template file

```
<div>
    Here this content is not loading
</div>
```

Here my problem is the content in html template file is not rendering in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your phtm and JS component file as follow

1) **phtml file**

```
<div id="chatlist" class="chatlist" data-bind="scope:'chatlist'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    phtml


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{

    "*": {

        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {            
            "components": {

                "chatlist": {
                      "component": "JC_ChatSupport/js/component/chatlist",

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

</div>
```

2) **Js File**

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent',
        'ko'
    ], function ($, Component, ko) {
        'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
                template: "JC_ChatSupport/chatlist"
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            console.log("hello, this is loading");
        },
    });
    }
);
```

Refresh the cache and check

Comment: Yes, it is a typo =P I wrote "chat" instead "chatlist" under component in phtml file. Anyways thanks for the answer. :)